# Problem for upload node package without developer dependencies to shared hosting from github

Tags: github, npm, npm-install, cpanel, npm-package

If I use any node package in my project where packages are not developer dependencies, also these packages are not uploaded to Github **because I added the node_modules folder to .gitignore**, so how can use it on my server (Shared Hosting/Cpanel) while there a package in node_modules folder and this folder are not backup to GitHub.

Shared hosting **doesn't allow me to install** packages again in hosting, only possible to upload files.